# kubectl - error x509 certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, k3s

I installed k3s on a single node. But when i try to connect to it remotly from my machine with kubectl I get the following error:

```sh
» kubectl version                                                                                                                                                                              
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"15+", GitVersion:"v1.15.8-beta.0", GitCommit:"6c143d35bb11d74970e7bc0b6c45b6bfdffc0bd4", GitTreeState:"archive", BuildDate:"2020-01-29T00:00:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.14beta1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

On the k3s server kubectl is installed and puts that out:

```sh
> kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.9+k3s1", GitCommit:"630bebf94b9dce6b8cd3d402644ed023b3af8f90", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-17T19:05:07Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.9+k3s1", GitCommit:"630bebf94b9dce6b8cd3d402644ed023b3af8f90", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-17T19:05:07Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I copied the k3s.yaml file from the server to my machine, renamed it to config and placed into ~/.kube/config.

I tried to use `--insecure-skip-tls-verify` and it works, but i don't want to use it everytime.

Comment: Hello, can you tell which guide did you use to spawn your `K3S` node? Also please update your `kubectl` as the official support is +1/-1 version between cluster and a client.

Comment: I installed it with the k3s installation script from [k3s.io](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/quick-start/)

Comment: I messed up the config file, so i had to copy it to my machine and it now works without an kubectl update 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are getting "Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" . It seems like you have copied only the ~/.kube/(config) file .
see the content of ~/.kube/(config) file and if that file entries of a CA root certificate , Client certificate and key entries then you need to copy all those three files also to your machine.

Comment: Where do you copy the missing files from? My .kube folder only has config file and cache folder

Comment: see the contents of the config file , they will show you the location of the required key and certificates. generally they will be /etc/kubernetes/pki folder

Answer (score 0):

I have got the exact same error closing my terminal. This was just an environment variable to set with the following command:

```
export KUBECONFIG="$(k3d kubeconfig write k3s-default)"
```